# How to tell EF not to Update Reference Type Property in Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encryption, ef-code-first

*Let's assume* I have these two Models

```
class Phone
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set;}

    public void Encrypt()
    {
        Encryptor.Encrypt(IMEI);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Phone Purchase { get; set; }

    public void Encrypt()
    {
        Purchase.Encrypt();
    }
}
```

Now it happens that, for security purposes, I can't have the IMEI stored in plain text in the database, so I have used the method of encryption I was forced upon; which returns a different encrypted string even for the same original string. I also have some logic to encrypt and decrypt the string every time the value is saved and retrieved to and from the database, respectively.

**So, what's the problem?**
The problem is that when I create a new `Person`, assign it a Phone and save it, EF will try to also save the Phone and, given that the IMEI string on the phone has changed, it will make a new entry on the DB.

Is there a way in which I can tell EF that a given object doesn't need to be saved? So that I can tell it to save the Person and its relationship to Phone, but not the phone itself? Or perhaps a way to discard the changes in an object so that EF ignores it?

### Update 1

I have some helper classes to simplify the logic in the controllers, as follows:

```
public class Helpers
{
    protected CustomDBContext Context { get; } = new CustomDBContext();

    public List<Phone> GetPhones()
    {
        return Context.Phones.Decrypt();
    }

    public void Save(List<Phone> phones)
    {
        phones.Encrypt();
        Context.Phones.AddRange(phones);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return Context.Persons.Decrypt();
    }

    public void Save(List<Person> people)
    {
        people.Encrypt();
        Context.Persons.AddRange(people);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have also updated the original definitions above. Notes:

- The `Encrypt` method in `Person` is just there because when I save Person its attached Phone is saved as well, which is I'm trying to avoid.
- In the `Encryptor` class I have extension methods to Encrypt all objects in a list, it's a basic iteration and encryption.
- I actually have more classes and inheritances and the whole shebang, I simplified it for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Why did the IMEI changed? Because it is decrypted? If this is the case maybe you can create a read-only property `DecryptedIMEI` that returns the decrypted IMEI and leave the `IMEI` property as it is (encrypted). You can put the [Ignore] attribute on the `DecryptedIMEI` property so EF will do nothing with it (although I think it should be sufficient to mark its setter as private)

Comment: @Leo Since I have full control of the code there are many ways in which I can solve the issue, of course yours is one of them, I can also store the encrypted values somewhere and and only re-encrypt if the values aren't there. I just thought that there's gotta be a way in which I can change the behavior of EF.

Comment: I don't understand why 1. The encrypted IMEI changes if you assign it to another person (which I understand you do). 2. Why EF would mark an entity as `Added` if one of its properties changes.

Comment: 1 The IMEI changes every time a Phone is saved, because I re-encrypt the value and the method returns a different encrypted string. 2 the IMEI is part of a Unique Index, so I guess that's why

Comment: Part 2 doesn't make sense. EF is oblivious of db indexes (even though it can create them through migrations). You should show (essential parts of) the code that gets and saves the entities.

Comment: This is completely based on your controller code, I believe. Show them please if possible, to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you save the entity, set it's navigation properties to null. This will keep the foreign keys but remove the entity reference associated with the navigation property. When the graph is searched for entities to add it will find nothing in place of the navigation property.

```
public void Save(List<Person> people)
{
    people.Encrypt();

    foreach(var person in people){
        person.Purchase = null;
    }

    Context.Person.AddRange(people);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

## Update

Make sure your entities' navigation properties are correctly modeled as well.

```
class Phone
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public void Encrypt()
    {
        Encryptor.Encrypt(IMEI);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }

    public virtual Phone Purchase { get; set; }

    public void Encrypt()
    {
        Purchase.Encrypt();
    }
}
```

You can find more information on navigation properties in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

## Update 2

If you are seeking to update your navigation properties as well as add the parent entities, simply attach them to the context before save.

```
public void Save(List<Person> people)
{
    people.Encrypt();

    foreach(var person in people){
        Context.Phones.Attach(person.Purchase)
    }

    Context.Person.AddRange(people);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This will allow you to update your encrypted IMEI in the database everytime you save.

Comment: But this will save the `Person` without `Phone` to the database, when the Person is retrieved the Phone will also be `null`. I fail to see how this works.

Comment: @PedroC88 My apologies, I assumed your entities were modeled correctly, see my update.

Comment: Why do I need to declare that virtual ICollection?

Comment: @PedroC88 that is an Entitiy Framework convention. It tells Entity Framework to setup a navigation property that points a given entity to related entities.

Comment: I'd like to read more about that, can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: @PedroC88 i've added the link in my answer, i hope this helps. I had similar issues a few months ago and it was quite frustrating.

Comment: Got it, the thing is that I didn't really need to add Reference Phone, in fact I wasn't actually using it for anything else than the relationship. Changing `Phone Purchase` in `Person` to `int PhoneID` did the trick. I think is just a matter of design methodology, I'm new to Code First and this seems like the old days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before `SaveChanges()`

```
db.Entry(person.Purchase).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it does't work. It also poses another problem, I would need to make sure to change all objects in the graph to Unchanged which is not that different from having to encrypt all objects in the graph.

Comment: what about this
context.Entry(person.Purchase).Property(p => p.IMEI).IsModified = false;

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you something like this:

```
var phone = dbContext.Set<Phone>().First(o=>ID == id);
phone.IMEI = Encrypt(phone.IMEI);
```

So, EF thinks, that phone is changed.
Maybe you should put logic into Phone class:

```
class Phone
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private string _imei;
    public string IMEI 
    { 
        get { return Decrypt(_imei);}
        private set { _imei = Encrypt(value); }
    }
}
```

When EF get entity from DB, it will once set IMEI value as encrypted and it wouldn't be in changed state.
If you give some code of getting phone from db, it will be better to understand.

Comment: Using it this way will not decrypt when being used in the application, remember that I only need it encrypted while stored, but decrypted while using it.

Comment: @PedroC88 you can store encrypted imei in Phone entity always

Comment: Yes, but with your code I won't be decrypted at runtime, and one of my problems right now is that when decrypt/encrypt back, the string is different

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you could create an additional property in `Phone` marked with [`NotMapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) attribute.

```
[NotMapped]
public string IMEIRaw { get; set; }
```

You would store decrypted value in this property.